# Strange ungooglable symbol. What does it mean? What is it called? §

Tags: word-choice

I'm not sure if this symbol will show up in everyone's browser, so I'll describe it also; It looks like an S with a o in the centre vertically. Here it is:  §

I've seen this symbol used as a bullet point more often than anything else. But I'm very interested to know more about it, what it means, where it comes from, and what it's called.

Can anyone explain this symbol?  §

Comment: Perhaps this would be more on-topic at [English Language & Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com) or [Graphic Design](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 1):

It's in the same category as the paragraph symbol, ¶. Both are sometimes used when giving a references, like to say "As described in ¶ 12, § 4", meaning "paragraph 12, section 4". They are also used when proof-reading text. The proof-reader will write one of these symbols in at a point where there should be a paragraph or section break.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so i found the ASCII code for the symbol and googled that. Which led to the conclusion that it is called a "Section Symbol" and is often used in legal documents to denote different sections.

As far as I'm concerned, that means its a glorified bullet point. ;-)

This question is redundant now, but if anyone else is looking to learn it; Here is a link to the relevant wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_sign

Comment: Bullet point is much smaller unit.  § corresponds to Article in law, a unit more similar to Section in creative writing, so it's more of a glorified three-asterisk-break, than a bullet point.